# Where do I put C libraries required by Python packages?

Tags: python, c, python-imaging-library

For example,On windows I have been trying to download Pillow for Python 2.7 using Pycharm's inbuilt pip like feature. Whenever I try to download Pillow it gives me error.

> ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using
>   --disable-zlib

I do not want to disable whatever functionality is provided by zlib by opting to disable it. I did download Zlib but not sure where to store it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail during installation of Pillow (Python module) in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux)

Comment: I am sorry for being a complete noob but as I can see on windows there are no direct commands to install a c library as there in Linux.

Comment: Well, you never mentioned Windows, but if you search StackOverflow you will find other answers too, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594800/how-to-install-pillow-on-windows-using-pip).

Answer (score 0):

For windows, it is easiest to download the installer package. It is available from the [pypi listing page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0). Scroll down the list of files and you should see `Pillow-2.7.0.win32-py2.7.exe`; click on that and run the executable to install Pillow.